# Cheerio on Node: crazy recursion that breaks the server

Tags: node.js, express, cheerio

I've an array of HTML string, I am trying to convert it to an array of Cheerio Object while changing the relative links to absolute links. While doing that, **the node app run into a crazy recursion, probably due to a stack overflow**.

For instance: the recursion will call _htmlToCheerio for infinite times when handling the 5th element of the "links" array.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
async.map(links, _htmlToCheerio, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        return cb(null, null);
    }
    return cb(null, results);
});

function _htmlToCheerio(html) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        return _updateLinksToAbsolute($);
}


function _updateLinksToAbsolute($) {

    var elms = $('a');
    elms.each(function(i, e) {

        var tagName = e.name;

        // <a href="">
        var href =  e.attribs['href'];
        if (tagName == 'a' && href && !isAbsoluteUrl(href)) {
            var newHref = URI.resolve(baseUrl, href);
            $(e).attr('href', newHref);
        }

    });

    return $;
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of parsing html you? And also example what you want get as result...

Comment: I don't remember the exact details and failed to find a relevant reference. But the memory performance of `map` can get much worse then the performance of `each`. I've seen the `map` being such a bad memory eater that it caused the stack overflow. So my advice is use `each` instead of `map`, built your results array by pushing processed links into a variable outside the closure (if you need them) and if that works for you then post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I don't see any recursion here. Is there a [mcve] and a clear error message?